# Cannot Find Symbol error when using .isVisible method

Tags: java, javascript, user-interface, compiler-errors

The following code gives me an error: cannot find symbol

```
public static boolean playerTurn = true;
public static boolean playerWon = false;
public static boolean player2Won = false;

public static TicTacToe board = new TicTacToe();

public static void main (String args []) {
    if (board.isVisible() == false){
        board.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the first part of code of the other class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle;
public class TicTacToe extends JFrame {
    public TicTacToe() {
            initComponents();
    }
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Use IDE's and know about shortcuts. I can help reduce such minor mistakes. :)  `if (board.isVisible == false)`  should be `if (board.isVisible() == false)`

Comment: consider adding stack trace here

Comment: I have added the parentheses it's now. `if (board.isVisible() == false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses from the method call. It's `isVisible()` not `isVisible`.

Comment: I have added them and still the same error. Let me update the question then

Comment: Make sure you're compiling the code you think you're compiling. It's not possible that isVisible() wouldn't be found from a subclass of JFrame.

Comment: Error Has been fixed. Seems like I had a mix of same named folders and some problems in the package. Thanks for all your help.